# the usage of "It's not that bad"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request

I wrote:

> I can't call the following riddle a standard one with a certain answer but it's not that bad.

A native speaker said to me that he can't get "***it's not that bad***" part. Is it ambiguous?
Maybe I should have said "*it's is not too bad*", but in general I use "not that bad" after I have criticized something and I want to make the situation better. For example, "*her cooking isn't good, but it's not that bad, it's worth to taste....*".

If it is an improper usage, then what can I say instead?

Comment: Seems understandable to me. I would probably reword as "I wouldn't call the following a standard riddle with a definite answer, but it's not that bad."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your phrase is understandable and often used.

The phrases

> it's not **that** bad
>   it's not **so** bad
>   it's not **too** bad

usually get used to take the sting out of criticism, however, when spoken if the qualifier is stressed it might be understood to be sarcastic

> I guess it's not **toooo** bad.
>   It's not **sooooo** bad.

meaning "it's horrible".

Answer (score 0):

It is ambiguous because no reference is given for comparison.  For example, I might say 
"The low temperature yesterday was 10 below, but today it won't be THAT low."  Here THAT refers clearly to yesterday's low temperature.

Comment: No. You're right that _that_ can be used in the way you're saying, as anaphora for something being compared; but you're ignoring a related but different use of _that_ in a negative polarity context meaning the same as _very_ or _too_, as Peter describes in his answer.